# Call webservice multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

In a database i have 30k users, each with a specified phonenumber. For each phonenumber, I will call a webservice which pulls some information for the user. Many users are not presented in the webservice, so I will just recieve null, but I don't know which users, and new users can be presented from time to time. The webservice updates realtime, so new results will come from minute to minute.
If the response is not null, and the recieved file is not the same as received last time, I create a PDF document from the recived XML-file.

The webservice call is started by a scheduled task which starts an .aspx-site with the following pseudo-code:

```
Foreach phonenumber {
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("webservice/phonenumber");

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        makePdf();
    }
}
```

The problem is, of course, that the request takes forever. For 30k users it would take about 7 hours. I have tried looking at async webservice calls, but couldn't get anything to work. Can someone point me in the right direction - if possible -, or tell me how I should go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you change the web service to accept multiple phone numbers and return multiple results ?

Comment: You should sync the data only for once and keep the records in your DB. It doesn't matter whether it take 7 hours or so as it's the one time process. Later you should only be requesting for data against newly added or updated users which will off-course doesn't take that much time.

Comment: he may not know whether a user has been updated, hence the need to check them all

Comment: hmmm ... hopefully the PDF generation part is separated from the webservice call. If not then there will be good performance improvement by separating it.

Comment: As Paul says, I have to check each phonenumber each time. And no, the PDF generation isn't separated. The other webservice is not mine, so I can't just change it. I was looking for something like calling it with threads or so...

Comment: You could use the `Parallel` class. See this [link](http://www.lovethedot.net/2009/01/parallel-programming-in-net-40-and.html)

Comment: Out of curiosity how this'll work with something like Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: You  should contact webservice creators. 30k calls its not an option at all, even in different threads. Maybe they could do another webservice which returns updated records and then you could get data for updated ones.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I'll go with the most of you, and contact the webservice creators and see what they have to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check if the time is in the webservice or in the PDF creation. If it is in the webservice, check if you are missing indexes, etc. To improve the webserice you can thing of getting multiple phonenumbers at the same time. If your problem is in the PDF creation, find a way to improve the creation of the pdfs. It's not clear what tools you are using to create a pdf at this moment.

Comment: The bottleneck is the Webservice. It's not my own webservice, and therefore I cannot improve it. Actually it's not a PDF I create, it's just a new XML I create out from a schema with a StreamWriter and XmlSerializer. The PDF is first created on the fly when the users clicks it - my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Why cant your service just implement a method that accepts a timestamp parameter and return a list(or array) of users that changed since that timestamp. That way you should be able to send request only for those users.